# What is the sunnah minimum and maximum beard length?

Tags: sunnah, beard

Can anyone quote a Hadith on minimum and maximum length of beard in Islam?

Answer (score 1):

**(SHIA point of view)**
Allamah al Majlisi (in the book of Heliatul-Motaqin):

> The Sunnah is keeping the beard in the normal (medial) size, not too
>   short, not too long. It is Makruh to have beard more than a
>   Qabzah(fist) and it has the probability of being Haram as well.

**About the minimum size of it:**

> According to his explanations, it ought not to be too short that be
>   similar to a person who cuts his beard completely.

**About the maximum size of it:
Imam Sadiq (a.s.) said:**

> The extra part of the beard(more than a fist) is in the fire.
>
> أبي عبدالله (الامام صادق (ع)) قال : ما زاد من اللحية عن القبضة فهو في
>   النار

**So, in accordance with the mentioned quotation, and likewise in accordance with your photo, I reckon your beard size is okay and at least taller than its minimum .**

---

Source:

[www.askdin.com](http://www.askdin.com/thread12487.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is not permissible for one to trim the hair along the jawbone unless it exceeds a fistful. Ulama have mentioned that it is wajib (obligatory) to grow the beard at least at fists’ length. The Ulama have deduced this from the following Hadith of the Prophet (SallAllahu Alayhi Wasallam) mentioned in Bukhari.....

You can read further here:
http://askimam.org/public/question_detail/18364

and here:
http://askimam.org/public/question_detail/18369

Comment: This is not entirely true in the sunni point of view.

Comment: @Kilise please explain a bit more.

Comment: Salam brother Zia. Meaning not all Ulama says it's wajib as he is saying. But it is true that the majority has said so.

Answer (score -1):

Beard growth varies - environment, genes and other factors play a role, for some people it just doesn't grow beyond a few patches.

So my friend, don't worry about its length but focus more on the spiritual aspect of religion and the life of Prophet Muhammad (PBUH)

Comment: -1 for not answering the question. I agree with you, but on a StackExchange site, answers have to... well, give an answer to what's directly being asked.

Comment: If you don't know how to answer why did you write this?

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be differences of opinion about the length of one’s beard. One should note however that it is Sunnah to have a beard, it is not fardh. So the question of someone being hurled to hell for not having a beard is most likely not correct. Allah knows best.

Comment: But the majority say it's wajib